# EventBroadcastProvider : would it be possible to hook and capture ANY events for ANY hierarchy?

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, .net-3.5

In this EventBroadcastProvider lib
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/event_broadcast.aspx

A click event and the target are predeclared so as the event to be captured by a particular hierarchy:

```
EventBroadcastProvider broadcastEvent =
     EventBroadcastProvider.CreateProvider(this.panel1, "Click");
```

Is it theorically possible to modify this lib so as AUTOMATICALLY FOR ANY event and for ANY arbitrary hierarchy, a child control would just call Relay within any of its event handler and the framework would induce the specific event and traverse the tree to distribute it to its hierarchy.

If not why - since WPF can do it ? What technically would prevent this (what feature would Microsoft access and not us so that they can do it but not we) ?

I doubt that in this case it is just syntactic sugar added by the compiler because It would be extremely inefficient and even impossible to predict all paths at design time, so there must be some hidden dynamic mechanism implemented at runtime. If so what it is and how one could recreate it ?

Comment: I think it's better you ask the Author about this.

Comment: MS builds the compiler and several features are AFAIK just "syntactic sugar" which is turn implemented by the compiler generating needed code to achieve them... your question is extremely general... what have you tried ?

Comment: Problem is that were are not Microsoft and so we do not have access to same stuff as them. I try to do the same thing as the guy above but more general ie not especially GUI.

Comment: The article is old and I don't want the hassle to register with the @Tigra, site at the moment and why wouldn't some bright people here not be able to know if it is possible or not ?

Comment: Libraries do provide extension mechanisms. If you feel that's not adequate choose another.

Comment: @Yahia I doubt that in this case it is just syntactic sugar because It would be extremely inefficient to predict all paths in advance, so there must be some hidden dynamic mechanism implemented.

Comment: @Tigran the author doesn't know better otherwise he would have not crafted the solution he exposed because it's just hard-wired.

Comment: @user310291: understand, but considering that he is an Author he *could* suggest a better solution that we are. Sure, it's not a rule.